# Share EVDO USB internet?

Tags: networking, internet, wireless-networking

I have a wireless router to which all my PCs are connected. Previously i was using DSL to share internet, now i have EVDO wireless USB on one of my PC, i want to share that internet to all my other PCs, any step by step guid?

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment.  Most EVDO plans are capped.  You risk running past the cap relatively quickly (couple of Microsoft, Adobe, ohter patches/updates per computer) and then you may possibly get billed a per-megabyte charge.  Before you do this, check your plan carefully!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to get a mobile broadband router with a USB input like the `Linksys WRT54G3GV2-ST`.  I personally owned one of these with a Sprint wireless USB adapter and it worked like a charm.